# Web service send id to another source and return information

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services

So I am kind of new to Web services, and I am trying to wrap my head around how it works.

Basically, I need to receive an ID from one side, pass it to another source which returns the employee information.

Now, this is what I did so far:

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Returns employee object for id")]
    public Employee GetEmployeeById(int Id)
    {
       // how to ?
        return new Employee( // data from outer source);
    }
```

I see the wsdl, where you can send the id to the function.

How does the other source get the information from my service?

Answer (score 1):

The another source means that anywhere you want to connect to. Maybe it's a database, other web service, or only a text file....

For example, you have a db that saves employee data. You can use Entity Framework to get employee data from db.

Like this:

```cs
[WebMethod(Description = "Returns employee object for id")]
public Employee GetEmployeeById(int Id)
{
    using(var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var emp = context.Employees.Where(x => x.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
        return emp;
    }
}
```